# Table quick filters

Tags: tables, filter, data-tables

Looking for examples of buttons above a table that can show you the numbers of a specific type of item and when you click them filter the table.

Any link or example will help a lot.

I have looked for lots of examples. One example I found is here.
Looking for similar examples, and too see if there are more complicated ones (filter based on more than one column).

[image]

Comment: Hi Zurim, have you tried searching online already? What did you like or not like about what you found? If you have more specific questions, we may be able to help you.

Comment: can you show us your efforts so far? This forum is most effective when people bring some mocks showing the specific situation, and outline any constraints they are dealing with.

Answer (score 1):

The most relatable example. Click on "Active" "Hot" etc and you know, the list is filtered.
[image]

### In your case, have an 'icon/name of the item + number of the specific item' in place of "Active","Hot".

Comment: This is an example of segmented controls. it works like tabs, meaning you cannot select/view more than one item at a time.

Comment: Yes that is correct. At the same time, the question doesn't seem to enquire for a need to see multiple filter results simultaneously. @Zurim just wants the numbers of results on each filter item. It is pretty simple to concatenate numbers at the end of the filter headers. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like [datatables](https://datatables.net), it is jquery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I assume that you are looking for examples of Multi-Select Filter Tags. As usual just like any other component, there are many names for the same functionality. This is mostly used as additional filters by enterprise applications to filter large data grids. I'm attaching few links below for your reference.

- Multi-Select Filter by Etrade Design System:
  https://etrade.design/filters#multi-select-filter
- Checkable Tags by Ant Design System:
  https://ant.design/components/tag/
- Static Chips by Predix GE:
  https://www.predix-ui.com/#/elements/px-chip
- Filter Chips by Material Design:
  https://material.io/components/chips/#filter-chips
- Tags on Zeplin to filter screens:
  https://blog.zeplin.io/organizing-screens-in-zeplin-with-tags-128dc3ed0749